# Questions about Electrum

Tags: wallet, electrum

I recently just installed the Electrum client and I have a couple questions.

1. Is a new address generated in the receiving addresses each time a transaction is made? It sounds like that in the documentation.
2. I was just testing the gap limit settings, and I lowered it to the default and now there is an address with a red line. How can I remove this address?
3. Is it possible to manually create a new address? Or do I just raise the gap limit?

I've used Google to look for some answers, but I am still very confused. Thank you for your input :)

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! This site works best when you ask one question per post. Please give each one a descriptive title that summarizes what you are asking.

Comment: Please just narrow it down to one question, then create another post for each of the other questions. Please flag for reopening then.